# What actually happens to LDPE Type 4 plastic when it is recycled?

Tags: recycling, plastic

> When LDPE Type 4 plastic used in plastic wrapping is recycled, what
>   is it used for?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.plasticsmakeitpossible.com/plastics-recycling/plastics-recycled-happens-recycled-plastics/

https://www.recycleandrecoverplastics.org/consumers/kids-recycling/plastics-can-become/

I have personally seen benches made out of used grocery bags. Those sites list more examples.